# SessionStorage value is not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript

I have two two pages:

**index.html**

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener("click",function(event){
            if(event.target.id == "login"){
                let username = document.getElementById("username");
                let password = document.getElementById("password");

                if(username.value != "" && password.value != ""){ 
                    formData.append("username",username.value);
                    formData.append("password",password.value);
                    fetch('upload.php', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: formData,
                    })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        if(data.message == "user exists"){
                            sessionStorage.setItem("key","loggedin");
                            window.location.href = "/admin_index.html";
                        }
                        else{
                            alert(data.error);
                            username.value = "";
                            password.value = "";
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        alert('Error: ' + error);
                    });
                }
                else{
                    alert("Please don't leave any field blank");
                }
            }
        })
</script>
```

**admin_index.html**

```
<script>
         if(sessionStorage.getItem("key") == "loggedin"){
             sessionStorage.removeItem("key");
         }
         else{
             window.location.href = "/index.html";
          }
</script>
```

Upon pressing the login button in `index.html` and going to `admin_index.html`, I expect the `sessionStorage` value to be removed. But when I use the Back button to return to `index.html` and then the Forward button to go back to the `admin_index.html`, the code in `admin_index.html` should return me back to `index.html` but doesn't. How do I fix this?

Comment: Every time you load `index.html` you will re-set the "loggedin" state, I'm not sure I understand the goal.

Comment: _"and going back to the admin_index.html"_ - _how_ are you "going back" to that?

Comment: The `back` and `forward` button in the chrome browser

Comment: Have you logged the value of `sessionStorage.getItem("key")` in the admin page, to verify it contains what you think ti should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `sessionStorage`, it's when/whether your code runs.

You've said:

> Again returning back to the previous tab (index.html) and going back to the admin_index.html should return me back to the former page. But it doesn't.

...and then [clarified in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77612551/javscript-sessionstorage-value-is-not-behaving-the-way-it-should#comment136826735_77612551) that you were "returning bacK" and "going back" using the Back and Forward buttons in the browser.

When you use Back and Forward to navigate, it doesn't necessarily re-run the top-level code of your page again. The browser can cache the contents of the window and just re-display them. I was able to replicate the scenario you describe using Chrome (but not, interestingly, using the Chromium-based browser Vivaldi).

You can solve that problem by using the [`visibilitychange` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event) instead, just wrap your top-level code in `admin_index.html` in a `visibilitychange` handler.

Here's the `index.html` page I used to replicate the problem:

```html
<input type="button" value="Other">
<script>
console.log("scratchpad load", Date.now(), sessionStorage.getItem("key"));
document.querySelector("input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("setting loggedin", Date.now());
    sessionStorage.setItem("key", "loggedin");
    window.location.href = "./admin_index.html";
});
</script>
```

...and the **original** JavaScript in `admin_index.html` page, which had the same problem yours did on Chrome:

```js
console.log("other", Date.now(), sessionStorage.getItem("key"));
if (sessionStorage.getItem("key") === "loggedin") {
    console.log("other removed key");
    sessionStorage.removeItem("key");
} else {
    console.log("no key, redirect");
    location.href = "./index.html";
}
```

Here's the **modified** modified `admin_index.html` code:

```js
window.addEventListener("visibilitychange", (event) => {
    console.log("other", Date.now(), sessionStorage.getItem("key"));
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("key") === "loggedin") {
        console.log("other removed key");
        sessionStorage.removeItem("key");
    } else {
        console.log("no key, redirect");
        location.href = "./index.html";
    }
});
```

When going Forward to the page, that code runs, and successfully detects that the `sessionStorage` didn't have the right key and sent me back to `index.html`.

You may need to do further tweaking (perhaps look at the document's [`visibilityState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState), and perhaps run your check both in top-level code *and* in the handler), but that should get you going the right way.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("key") == "loggedin"){
        sessionStorage.removeItem("key");
    }
    window.location.href = "/index.html";     
</script>
```

this will check the key is present if so it will remove the key. in either of the case page will redirect back to index.html.
i the code you wrote if the key is present it will remove and does not redirect.